# Windows does not start, and I can not format

Tags: windows-7

Sorry for my English...

to two days ago was my good computer running until the HD source and burn because of a RADIUS, thank God the remaining parts were intact!
This morning I bought a 230w atx source and an HD 1tb, I do not remember the brand, ta my room without light or I would open the PC and see the brand.
 
My computer after you installed the source and HD worked good, but now the night he hung up and was caught on the "Starting Windows", I tried to format, and after loading the files appeared a black screen with an arrow mouse and large, do not get out of it, what can be?
 
Note: Before burning was quick after I installed the drivers for the "Driver Booster" began the 100% CPU until turned off and not turned over. And it has a red LED that does not erase it for the cabinet.

Comment: Because of a Radius how is an authentication standard to blame for your problems?  Edit your question to include all this missing details, you failed to provide us, then we might be able to help you

Comment: Yes burned the source and drive after a heavy rain with thunder and lightning. I can not provide more information, are those that have

Comment: Undoing any damage Driver Booster has done would be good too, rollback if possible, to before that pile of **** got its hands on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there could be many issues here, but assuming the format failed, there may or may not be a good version of your OS still installed.

I would unplug any external drives (which may cause issues booting) and assuming that you are using Windows, try booting into Safe Mode by "[press and hold the F8 key as your computer restarts. You need to press F8 before the Windows logo appears. If the Windows logo appears, you'll need to try again[...]On the Advanced Boot Options screen, use the arrow keys to highlight the safe mode option you want, and then press Enter.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/advanced-startup-options-including-safe-mode-b90e7808-80b5-a291-d4b8-1a1af602b617#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7) "

This will (hopefully) bypass any issues with programs that may be causing the computer not to boot correctly.

If you still cannot get in to Windows, there still may be other issues such as missing files.

Comment: So I deconectar the sata cables and take the tests ?

Comment: If it is a hard drive outside the case, yes. If it is inside the case, do not disconnect the cables.

Comment: internal HD , went into safe mode and load the files locked in `\windows\system32\drivers\Classpnp.sys`. 
Actually, after I updated my drivers by `driver booster` this happened .

Comment: It may be possible driver booster messed with something or it may be a bios issue. But first, make sure that your hard drive is listed correctly in the bios. You may want to toggle the settings there ("ACHI" to "IDE") or vice versa to test things out. Assuming that doesn't help, you may need to try to repair the installation. Do the same thing you did for Safe Mode but "use the arrow keys to highlight Repair your computer, and then press Enter." If Repair your computer isn't listed as an option, then your computer may not include preinstalled recovery options.

Comment: Here is a separate repair disc image if it does not -- https://neosmart.net/blog/2009/windows-7-system-repair-discs/. Note there may also be free images on the net. Or you may be able to make one with the computer you have it if is Windows 7 as well.

Comment: Ok, 
I just find it strange why can not format , ok I'll see the link you gave me . Thx bro.

Comment: Hope you get things solved.

Comment: It's hard dude :/

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to hear it. =)

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve was simple:

I went into the bios by pressing the `Del key`. I changed my `SATA` setting to `AHCI`.

Now I can format without problems.

Reference - [PT-BR]: http://www.blogdainformatica.com.br/windows-nao-inicia-apos-classpnp-sys/